# how can I designe a workflow of continous integration for wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, database-versioning

how can I use wordpress core for continuous integration/deployment. it seems wordpres completely work with database changes. it means when I change my local and users change production there is a conflict and need merge on db .

Answer (score 0):

Continuous Integration with systems like Git and Bitbucket is for files only, and Wordpress does not use Schema Builders like Laravel. For database changes, you can simply export production and import to local before testing changes then push live, or you can look for schema modifiers like [ApexSQL Diff](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx)